# Can't use `contains` filtering query in Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I want to filter the returned array of resource groups by partial name match. According to [the docs on JMESPath functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/query-azure-cli?tabs=concepts%2Cbash#jmespath-functions), I can do the following.

```
az vm list --resource-group QueryDemo  
  --query "[?contains(storageProfile.osDisk.managedDisk.storageAccountType,'SSD')]  
    .{Name:name, Storage:storageProfile.osDisk.managedDisk.storageAccountType}"
```

I adapted it to my needs and filter by the property *name*, returning the whole shabang.

```
az group list --query "[?contains(name,'se')]"
```

However, it seems that I'm failing to follow the syntax because the console barks at me saying:

> ] was unexpected at this time.

I'm sure there's something wrong with the contents of the brackets and something more needs to be added so that the closing one **will be** expected. But it beats me what that could be. I'm starting to suspect that the syntax may be applicable for virtual machines but not resource groups but that sounds insane. (Also, I tried to execute the exact command, despite not having any virtual machines in my environment, still getting the same error.)

Comment: This error happens only when you run in PowerShell Mode.
Can you please try in Normal Command Prompt Mode ?

Comment: you could try this guidance if powershell is needed https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/dev/doc/quoting-issues-with-powershell.md#workaround-the-stop-parsing-symbol

Comment: @ShivaPatpi What is *Normal Command Prompt Mode*? I'm in PowerShell when executing that method. Are you saying to switch to Bash, CMD or something like that? I intend to create a set of PS1 scripts to do perform certain tasks so I'm sort of relying on that. If I can't use *contains* nor other functions like this, how do I do that in PowerShell? I fear it's going to become very clunky and awkward if I chose less optimal approach.

Answer (score 0):

The `contains` in Azure Cli is correctly used in below way and modified your given query and followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-group-list):

```
az group list --query "[?contains(name,'se')].{Name: name}"
```

Output:

[image]

It requires a `DOT` Operator in Azure Cli.  Here I wanted name so given name, if you want all properties where name contains se then use below query:

```
 az group list --query "[?contains(name,'se')].{Name:name,Id:id,ProvisioningState:ProvisioningState,ManagedBy:managedBy,Location:location,Tags:tags,Type:type }"
```

[image]